# Inputs not recognized regularly inside a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes I have to introduce an input twice in the console for my while loop to recognize it. The code is really simple and I can't seem to find the reason why this is happening.

I've tried changing the syntaxis and revising the while loop, but still the structure is so simple it shouldn't fail. Every time I get the same error, even though the console doesn't recognize it.

```
note_dict = {
    "F2": 1,
    "F#2": 2,
    "Gb2": 2,
    "G2": 3,
    "G#2": 4,
    "Ab2": 4,
    "A2": 5,
    "A#2": 6,
    "Bb2": 6,
    "B2": 7,
    "C3": 8
}
bases = []
print("Introduce your inputs: (Write exit to finish) \n")

while True:
    base = input("")
    if base == "exit":
        break
    if base in note_dict:
        bases.append(note_dict[base])
        continue
    else:
        print("Not recognized")
        continue


print(bases)
```

Expected something like this (in console):

```
Introduce your inputs: (Write exit to finish)

Bb2
B2
C3
C4
Not recognized
exit
[6, 7, 8]
```

What I atually got (in console too):

```
Introduce your inputs: (Write exit to finish)
Bb2
B2
C3
C4
C4
Not recognized <- Had to write it twice to say that
exit
exit <- Again, it didn't recognize it until the second time
[6, 8] <- The results aren't even right...
```

Comment: I only typed C4 once and it was recognized.  Not sure why you are seeing something different.

Comment: The problem is not in your code. What console/terminal are you using?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code shows the expected result.

Comment: How exactly are you running this? What is the OS?

Comment: I've just tested it on an online interpreter and the code works just fine, as you said. I'm on an i7-4700MQ laptop with Windows 10 1803 installed. I don't usually work on it, but I've installed python 3.7 on it because I'm away from my main pc. I run the code from the CMD without any virtual environments...